# How to fix the container takes the ::after styles

Tags: css

I'm doing some work on my website, I wanted to put that border thing with ::after(I don't want to do it with border-bottom because I want to set specific width) method, unfortunately when I'm trying to set the "**::after**" to position "**absolute**", and the container of it to position "**relative**", but the problem is the container somehow gets the position "**absolute**" which I don't want it to

I tried to set inline style but it doesn't give best performance.

```
HTML: 

<h2 class="special-heading">Our Team</h2>


CSS:

.special-heading {
    position: relative
}


.special-heading:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left:0;
    width: 40px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this instead of `top: ...px`

```
margin-top: 10px;
```

But not sure!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want to achieve by replacing the line `top: 10px` with `bottom: 0`.

I tested it in codepen and the `.special-heading` got the `position: relative` properly.